# getting JSON into d3.js file

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, json, d3.js

I have a chart created using `d3.js` where if you hover over the months,the weekly scores are found.

Fiddle link to the chart I am talking about here : https://jsfiddle.net/qp7L1hob/1/

I also have a table in my DB where I maintain the record of the scores of the Employees every week.What you see here is only for four weeks - (week1 to week4) but in my DB I have record for all the weeks of the months.This is just for reference .

**Table pointsScored :** 
[image: score]
After the user logs in,I want to display only that person's relevant scores.Lets say if Rob logs in,his score for week1 is 47 , week2 is 44, week3 is 44 and week4 is 43.

**Issue :** I  am `Using php to extract json` from `SQL` server . Below `PHP` file does that.

**The problem is that how do I get the `JSON` into the `d3.js` file, i.e the above fiddle.**

please help.

`json` file (lets name it as `data.php`) :I understand that I need to include this `data.php` in the above `d3.js` file.But not sure how.

```html
<?php
session_start();
$servername="xxxxxxx";
$connectioninfo=array('Database'=>'xxxxxx');
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($servername,$connectioninfo);
if($conn)
{
echo 'connection established';

}
else
{
echo 'connection failure';
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}

$q1="SELECT WeekNumber,pointsRewarded,EmployeeID FROM pointsBadgeTable WHERE EmployeeID = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' ";
$stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q1);
if($stmt==false)
{
echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}
do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $result[] = $row;
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));


sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first
echo json_encode($result); //You will get the encoded array variable
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by getting data into D3.js. If you look closely, you are referencing an array 'dataWeeks' when showing the tooltip (Weeks info). One way to do this , is to first populate the array  and generate graph then. Pass the dataWeeks (filled with data from endpoint) to the generating function.

Comment: @FarooqKhan thanks for the input. I am new to d3.js, so need little help here to pass dataweeks to the gererating function.I cannot populate the array,as the data is dynamic.but is it possible to echo the variable from the json into the dataweeks. How will you do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you the direction to understand, you can use AJAX to call your php file and get data

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       var dataObj = JSON.parse(response.responseText); // parse data into JSON object
       chartDrawFunction(dataObj); // call draw here, to load chart only when you have data

    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "data-url-to-be-passed", true); // pass the URL here
xhttp.send();
```

## Update

As i understood the question other way if PHP file was separate from the view. In view you can echo the data in a JavaScript variable like

```
var data = <?php echo data; ?>;
```

Comment: Why do we make a Ajax call in d3.js file here

Comment: How do you plan to get data from database?

Comment: I am getting the data as json from the DB using the above code.I just need to echo the data in the d3.js .I just have no idea how to do it .

Comment: Apologies, i might have overlooked your question and understand it the other way. I have updated my answer.